# Getting Payload Validation Error while creating User in Auth0

Tags: c#, auth0, webapi

I'm getting the below Payload validation error while creating an Auth0 user:

> Payload validation error: 'Additional properties not allowed: $type (consider storing them in app_metadata or user_metadata. See "Users Metadata" in https://auth0.com/docs/api/v2/changes for more details)'.

Here is the payload that I am sending (*redacted irrelevant information*):

[image: img]

This is how I am making the call:

```cs
//Calling to Get the token, working fine!
var managementApiClient = new ManagementApiClient(await GetAccessTokenAsync(), _config.Domain);

// create the user in Auth0
var result = await apiRetryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
    async () =>
        await managementApiClient.Users.CreateAsync(userCreateRequest)
);


return result;
```

The client is written in C#, and .Net Core - the main thing that I couldn't find anywhere related to this is I am sending **type** within the input parameters.

Comment: No answers yet! Any guidance will be helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have followed this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/627356/how-to-not-serialize-the-type-property-on-json-objects, and tried all the options, including changing the parameter from existing type to break it in individual params, but no luck - getting the same exception. Basically the CreateAsync() is serializing my object and introducing $type.So the problem is very clear, need to found how to ensure it does not do so.

Comment: which version of .net core are you using?

Comment: Is it possible, that your Json settings generates `$type` property?

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 used [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serialization objects. We can see in the Auth0 GitHub repository ([HttpClientManagementConnection](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.net/blob/master/src/Auth0.ManagementApi/HttpClientManagementConnection.cs#L20) class).

And Auth0 serialization settings looks fine. But Serializer generated `$type` property for some reasons.

For generating of `$type` property Json.NET used [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm) serialization settings.

It seems your JSON serialization settings were redefined. Try to use global JSON [DefaultSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DefaultSettings.htm) and setup `TypeNameHandling` property globally to [None](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm).

Answer (score 0):

When sending the headers, make sure they are correct, the `-d` options will default to sending a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

In the end *you want to be sending over JSON*. And, you should be also sending an additional header: `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Before returning your result double check its in JSON format, this might help you from [Auth0 Site](https://community.auth0.com/t/unable-to-patch-user-with-app-metadata/12574/4)